# How to remember file loaded while going back?

Tags: php, file, back

I am working on one web application where i upload one file using upload method in php and in the next page (upload.php), i process the data and display the content but i have one back button.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Select image to upload:
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
 </form>
```

**procees.php**

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script> 

<?php
   /*process uploaded file*/
?>
```

when i click Go Back button, again i need to upload the file, if there any way to remember the same file(which i uploaded) even though i go back?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `window.history.back();`
just redirect the user to the page you want him to go, and process the image before displaying the button, is good practice